# Clarification on this corollary of the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am given the following corollary without proof:

> A family of continuous functions on a compact metric space into
>   $\mathbb R^m$ is compact iff it is closed, equicontinuous and bounded.

Does the last word above mean pointwise bounded or uniformly bounded?
(I'm pretty sure equicontinuous above means uniformly equicontinuous.)

Comment: The family you consider is a subspace of the metric space $C(K,\mathbb{R}^m)$ ($K$ is a certain compact space) where the metric is induced by the supremum norm. Thus if you talk about boundedness you mean always uniform boundedness.

Comment: @DamianSobota Consider the related corollary here: math.stackexchange.com/q/508999/21813 where we're also talking about a family of bounded functions (i.e. it has a sup norm), but yet a pointwise bound is specified. Would you mind to clarify?

Comment: I was wrong. The Arzela-Ascoli theorem assumes pointwise boundedness of the family, ie. for each $x\in K$ there is $M>0$ st. for each $f$ from the family it holds $|f(x)|<M$. Note that $M$ depends on $x$ but is common for all functions from the family.

Comment: In metric spaces every compact set has to be bounded in the sense of the metric. So the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem just implies that a pointwise bounded and equicontinuous family is also uniformly bounded (ie. bounded in the supremum metric). And one more thing: if you consider a compact metric space, then equicontinuity of a compact family of continuous functions is equivalent to uniform equicontinuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adjective `bounded' refers here to the family of continuous functions, i.e. there is a universal constant $M$ so that for each function $f$ in the family and every $x$ in the domain, $$|f(x)| \leq M.$$ You can get counterexamples if you don't assume uniform boundedness. Let your compact metric space be an arbitrary nonempty metric space, and consider the family $$\mathcal F := \{f_c \textrm{ : } c \in \mathbb R\},$$ where $f_c$ is the function defined by $$c \mapsto (c,0,\ldots,0).$$ Clearly each element of the family is uniformly continuous (and the family itself is equicontinuous), pointwise bounded, and the family itself contains its limit points, so it is closed. However $\mathcal F$  is not sequentially compact, take for instance the sequence $$n \mapsto f_n$$ which has no convergent subsequence.

EDIT: In light of the comment below, I may have misinterpreted the OP's meaning of pointwise boundedness.

However, let me point out that if we define as in the comment a pointwise bound on $\mathcal F$ to mean that for each $x$ in the domain, there exists $M$ so that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $f \in \mathcal F,$ then equicontinuity of $\mathcal F,$ pointwise boudnedness of $\mathcal F$, and compactness of the underlying metric space implies that (without appealing to the Arzela-Ascoli thm) $\mathcal F$ is uniformly bounded. In particular, the hypotheses in the OP's question imply that $\mathcal F$ is uniformly bounded even if $\mathcal F$ is only assumed at first to be pointwise bounded. Here is the proof.

If $\mathcal F$ is pointwise but not uniformly bounded, then there exists a sequence of points $x_n$ in the (compact) domain and functions $f_n \in \mathcal F$ so that $f_n(x_n) \to \infty$. Thus, in order to prove that pointwise boudnedness implies uniform boundedness, it suffices to prove that for any such sequence $f_n(x_n)$, there exists a bounded subsequence. Since the domain is compact, we may choose a subsequence of $x_n$ (which we still denote $x_n$) that converges to a limit, say $x_n \to x$. Then
$$|f_n(x_n)| = |f_n(x_n) - f_n(x) + f_n(x) - f(x) + f(x)| \leq$$ 
$$|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f(x)| + |f(x)|.$$ The term  $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x)|$ is bounded since the sequence $f_n$ is in particular equicontinuous and since if $n$ is large, $x_n$ is close to $x$. The term $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ is bounded since $\mathcal F$ is pointwise bounded, and $f(x)$ is of course independent of $n$. Thus the subsequence $f_n(x_n)$ is uniformly bounded, as desired.

This shows that it `doesn't matter' whether or not you interpret the hypothesis to mean pointwise bounded (in the sense defined in this edit) or uniformly bounded. However, since pointwise bounded is a weaker concept, the theorem is stronger if you only assume pointwise boudnedness in the hypothesis.

Comment: Every $f_c$ is bounded but $\mathcal{F}$ is not pointwise bounded. Pointwise boundedness means that for every $x\in X$ (the compact space) there is $M>0$ such that for every $f\in\mathcal{F}$ it holds $|f(x)|<M$. The Arzela-Ascoli Theorem assumes this kind of boundedness. Of course, uniform boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$ implies pointwise boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: ... and the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem implies that a pointwise bounded and equicontinuous family is also uniformly bounded as every (relatively) compact set in a metric space has to be bounded in the sense of the metric.

Comment: "However, since pointwise bounded is a weaker concept, the theorem is stronger if you only assume pointwise boudnedness in the hypothesis." But the theorem would be stronger only in one direction; it would be weaker in the other direction where "bounded" is the conclusion instead of the hypothesis.

Comment: @Ryan No, because once you make the pointwise bounded conclusion, then use my argument again to conclude uniform boundedness.

Comment: I mean the theorem as it stands (without having to make any futrher inference) would be weaker (in one direction).

Comment: The theorem as it stands is correct when bounded is replaced with pointwise bounded, due to the edit in my answer.